# Check box Styling Tips

Tags: html, css, mobile, checkbox, cross-browser

Testing my application on different browser the styling of a check box doesn't seem to be easy or very nice..

On chrome you get a slight orange box round the checkbox.

But when setting things like background or border and running my application on my blackberry. It makes no difference.

My check box is simple like this

```
<label for="chk">Checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk"/>
```

How hard is it to bold the checkboxes label when the checkbox is in focus?

My aim is basically, normal check when not focus, some kind of effect that user knows when its focused e.g. Bold Label, Border anything?

This must work on chrome + blackberry web browser and web works...

Also confused why the check box styling is strange compared to everything else...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these out:

- http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
- http://cssdeck.com/item/321/css-checkbox-styles

Comment: I didn't see anything in these links about `:focus` - do you have a link for that?